# How to escape ' in docker-compose entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use this for create databases and init user on an docker-compose up -d

```
entrypoint:
  sh -c "
    echo 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS firstDB;CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS secondDB;' > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql;
    /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  "
```

This is working very well, but here is the problem

```
sh -c "echo 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS firstDB;CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS secondDB;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;' > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql;
    /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  "
```

I tried to escape the ' with '' or \' .... nothing is working.

Any help please how to escape the ' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, you don't need to.  Create a local file `init.sql` that contains that string; since it's just a file you don't need to do any shell escaping at all.  Use a `volumes:` declaration to mount the file into the container, and use the image's default entrypoint.  For example:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8'
    volumes:
      - 'mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
      - './init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql' # <-- this
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
volumes:
  mysql:
```

If you have more than one file, you can put them in a shared directory and mount that entire directory into the container.  If you need special options like you show, you can put those options (only) as the `command:`

```
command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

If you really need to do this as a complex script, I'd suggest writing it into a shell script rather than trying to do it inline; it saves one level of quoting, and you can use shell features like heredocs to simplify this further.  I'd probably build this into a custom image, but you could mount it into the container in the same way as above.

If all else fails, you can try running the command in your local shell but put `echo` in front of it, or removing the second command from the `sh -c` wrapper.  This will print out the command line after the shell does all of its quoting and other expansions so you'll get a clearer picture of what's getting written out.

```sh
echo sh -c "echo 'CREATE DATABASE ...'"
```

(If you need to write out literal quotes inside a quoted string inside a quoted string, it's nasty.  The one variant I might try is wrapping the `echo` parameter in double quotes, which need to be escaped because they're inside a double-quoted string

```sh
sh -c "echo \"CREATE ... 'root'%'@' ...\" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm I am a bit confused

```
  db:
image: mysql:latest
container_name: mysql

restart: always

networks:
    my-container-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.30.10
ports:
    - 60000:3306

command : --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass

volumes:
    - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

entrypoint:
    sh -c "echo \"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS spotweb;CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS nextcloud;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;FLUSH PRIVILEGES;CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS spotweb;CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS nextcloud;CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'spotweb'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'spotpass';CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'spotweb'@'%' identified with mysql_native_password by 'spotpass';CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'nextcloud'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'nextpass';CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'nextcloud'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'nextpass';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON spotweb.* TO 'spotweb'@'localhost';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON spotweb.* TO 'spotweb'@'%';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nextcloud.* TO 'nextcloud'@'localhost';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nextcloud.* TO 'nextcloud'@'%';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;\" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql;/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

mySQL Server starts, but no User or Datebase is beeing created :-(